# hidraw set-report/send-report doesn't work with Android 6.x

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-source, android-6.0-marshmallow, hid

I have a bluetooth hid device that I need to communicate with. Target platform is Android 5.x+. Currently testing on Nexus 7 2013 tablet.

My code works fine on android 5.x, I am able to receive, send and set reports on Android 5.x.

On Android 6.x, I am only able to receive reports sent by device, but I am not able to send or set reports. It looks like my set/send report requests are silently ignored by HID/BT stack.

The code that talks to /dev/hidraw* nodes runs as a native daemon as root.

Are there any new requirements to be able to set/send reports to Bluetooth hid devices on Android 6.x? Is there any changes I could make to AOSP to allow this to work?

[Update]
Logcat says:

`05-17 11:22:56.085 2455-4061/com.android.bluetooth E/bt_btif: uhid_event: Invalid size read from uhid-dev: 4108 != 4`

I do not understand how reading from uhid will return only 4 bytes! First 4 bytes are supposed to contain only the `type` of event. Is there any scenario that will result in a `read()` of less than `sizeof(struct uhid_event)` bytes?

Could this indicate a bug in uhid driver?

Comment: I have a growing suspicion that uhid driver might be depleted of working code in android kernel source. I'll update when I get more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked available kernel sources and found that hidraw driver does not contain usable source to feed reports to /dev/hidraw* nodes

I also found that Bluedroid correctly receives and sends reports internally.

Simplest method to get/set/send reports I found was to modify bluedroid to communicate directly with my App for vendor-specific reports. I integrated my daemon into Bluedroid directly.